# Spring import all configuration files in a directory into another configuration file without specifying the profiles / filenames explicitly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there a way to import all configuration files in a directory without having to explicitly specify their profiles / filenames one by one?

I thought of using `spring.config.import` but it doesn't seem to support specifying a directory or pattern to dynamically import whatever configuration files are contained within the directory.

For example:

I have the main config `application.yml` and children config in the `config/` directory, which contains `application-test1.yml`, `application-testN.yml` and so on.  I want to automatically load all the config files under the directory without specifying them explicitly in `application.yml`.

I tried these below, but they don't work.

```
spring
    config
        import: classpath:config/

spring
    config
        file: file:config/*/
```

Answer (score -1):

`spring.config.location=classpath:/custom-config/`

This should load the configuration from the specified folder. As per the different profiles configurations, only active profiles configuration would be imported, so you need to make sure that the standard configuration file that gets loaded activates these profiles (eg. using `spring.profiles.include`)

Further references:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-files

Comment: Hm, doesn't seem to work in my case.  I added `spring.config.location=classpath:config/` (with yaml syntax) to the main `application.yml` but the children config files under the directory weren't loaded.

Comment: I realised my question was probably not clear enough.  I just updated it.

Comment: classpath:config/ should already be scanned by Spring by default. If it doesn't pick up the configuration inside, it is simply because it's related to profiles which are not enabled when you're running your application. You can specify the active profiles in several ways, eg.: mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev,test1,test2,someOtherProfile OR via application.yml using spring.profiles.include / spring.profiles.active

Comment: That is the problem I'm trying to solve.  Is there anyway to not have to explicitly specify the profiles one by one?  It doesn't seem like I can use patterns?